# Accept a generic type or an array of same generic type

Tags: typescript, generics, serialization

I'm going to deserialize a JSON request from a REST endpoint. That endpoint can respond with a single object or with an array of same objects of couse.

eg. single customer

```
/api/customer/1
{ name: 'Matt', phone: '+010101010' }
```

eg. multiple customers

```
/api/customer/
[
   {name: 'Matt', phone: '+010101010'},
   {name: 'John', phone: '+99999999'},
   {name: 'Doe', phone: '+123131321'}
]
```

I want to deserialize with a function like that:

```
const mapper = <T>(type: DTOResponse<T>, data: any): T | T[] | null => {
    let result: T | T[];

    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        result = data.map(x => plainToClass(type, x));
    }
    else {
        result = plainToClass(type, data);
    }

    return result;
 }

 const resAsArrayObj = mapper<DtoModel>(DtoModel, dtoArray);
 const resAsSingleObj = mapper<DtoModel>(DtoModel, dtoSingleObj);
```

**Ok. That code works.** But i prefer to know that the returned object is the same type as the generic that I've passed.

I want something like that (see the **[]** in the first statement).

```
 const resAsArrayObj = mapper<DtoModel[]>(DtoModel[], dtoArray);

 const resAsSingleObj = mapper<DtoModel>(DtoModel, dtoSingleObj);
```

EDIT: Here the [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-herschel-5puvx)

Comment: Please share reproducable example in ts playground

Comment: How I can share a ts playground with some external dependencies? Like @automapper/core?

Comment: You can use codesandbox

Comment: Nice. Here the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-herschel-5puvx